# How does MIKROS know which users are cheaters or trolls?

Tags: mikros, mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics

I'm having trouble identifying how MIKROS tracks players who use exploits or are just a nuisance in general.

These are the code blocks I'm using to code user sign-in and sign-up:

For user sign-in:

```
SigninRequest.Builder()
    .Username(username)
    .Email(email)
    .Password(password)
    .Create(signinRequest =>
    {
        MikrosManager.Instance.AuthenticationController.Signin(signinRequest, delegate (MikrosUser mikrosUser)
        {
            // signed in successfully.
        },
        delegate (MikrosException mikrosException)
        {
            // handle authentication error
        });
    },
    onFailure =>
    {
        // handle failure
    });
```

For user sign-up:

```
SignupRequest.Builder()
    .Username(username)
    .Email(email)
    .Password(password)
    .Create(signupRequest =>
    {
        MikrosManager.Instance.AuthenticationController.Signup(signupRequest, delegate (MikrosUser mikrosUser)
        {
            // signed up successfully.
        },
        delegate (MikrosException mikrosException)
        {
            // handle authentication error
        });
    },
    onFailure =>
    {
        // handle failure
    });
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MIKROS registration/authentication you will receive score information about the user.

For sign-in

```
SigninRequest.Builder()
        .Username(username)
        .Email(email)
        .Password(password)
        .Create(signinRequest =>
        {
            MikrosManager.Instance.AuthenticationController.Signin(signinRequest, delegate (MikrosUser mikrosUser)
            {
                // signed in successfully.
            },
            delegate (MikrosException mikrosException)
            {
                // handle authentication error
            });
        },
        onFailure =>
        {
            // handle failure
        });
```

For sign-up

```
SignupRequest.Builder()
        .Username(username)
        .Email(email)
        .Password(password)
        .Create(signupRequest =>
        {
            MikrosManager.Instance.AuthenticationController.Signup(signupRequest, delegate (MikrosUser mikrosUser)
            {
                // signed up successfully.
            },
            delegate (MikrosException mikrosException)
            {
                // handle authentication error
            });
        },
        onFailure =>
        {
            // handle failure
        });
```

Both will return a response body with a `user{}` object that will include scoring information for that particular user. Here is the short version of it.

Response Ex-

```
"user": {
            ....
            "id": "172",
            "email": "mikros3@test.com",
            "username": "mikros3",
            "spendingScore": "0",
            "activityScore": "0",
            "reputationScore": "0", <-- this is the score for hackers/trolls
        }
```

Per the documentation, anyone with a score less than 7 you should be cautious about. It means that user has many negative offenses. The specifics of the offenses are not disclosed. But the only reasons you lose Reputation is from other users reporting you as a troll, hacker or other offensive behavior. To lower your score this has to happen pretty often and come from many different users.

Ref- https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/scores#reputation-score

Note: It has been mentioned by the MIKROS developers that they will be exposing a stand alone API for retrieving scores and more details about users outside of register/authentication. It's a feature on their roadmap.